# Azure storage account permissions for data management but not delete create metadata like new table or container or delete a table

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am looking for a way to share a connectionstring with all developers so that they can create data/delete data from all services in storage account like Table/Blob/file etc but cant create a new table or delete a table.
How can I generate such a key for them?
Access keys give all permissions and while generating SAS token I dont see an option to remove delete permissions for tables/containers etc.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

Generating **SAS Token or Connection string** by giving permissions like Delete and Create will allow the users not only to create/delete data from all services but also allows users to create/delete Table/Blob/file etc.

[image]

To restrict the access, try adding the permission at Blob Level so that, the users create new data.
Not Assigning the Permissions at container level will not allow users to create any new blob/table.

I Generated the SAS Token in **Blob Level** like below:

[image]

You can also make use of below **CLI command to Generate SAS Token**:

```bash
New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Context $ctx 
    -Container <container> 
    -Blob <blob> 
    -Permission rcd 
    -ExpiryTime <date-time>
    -FullUri
```

[image]

These are the operations you can perform to Generate SAS Token to restrict user access.
Based on your requirement it is not possible to generate SAS Token or Connection String for those operations as SAS Token can only be applied for Container/File/Table/ level or Blobs/Entity/Queue and Connection String is generated at Storage Account Level.

**Note** that: If you generate the SAS Token with Create permission on Container/Blob, the user will be able to create or access Container and Blob and same with Files, Tables, Queues.

Comment: thanks for validating it! What I am trying to achieve is that user can do anything with data at the Table/Container level i.e. delete/read/create new data(blob or a row in the table). But then cant let say delete a table all together or delete a container.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to achieve your scenario.